# Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 Static IP hostname not resolving in Lan

Tags: networking, server, dns, static-ip

**What is working:**

- Internet access
- The configured Static IP
- Pinging other machines in Lan (IP and hostname)

**What I'm trying to solve:**

I can't ping/ssh etc. the Ubuntu server from other clients using the hostname. IP works fine.

I have an AVM Fritz Box router acting as the DHCP/DNS server. It took a few days for my Windows 10 machine to be available via hostname, I thought it would be the same with the server, but it's been a week and still nothing.

The router displays the hostname in the gui.

Upon installation I chose DHCP, I could reach the server using the hostname, it stopped working when I switched to static IP.

**/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml:**

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  version: 2

  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp2s0]
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.4/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.1.1
        search:
          - fritz.box
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

I am using LXD containers, that's why I need the bridge. But it wasn't working even before I added br0.

**What I tried:**

- Messing around with *systemd-resolved*
  I disabled it, as suggested somewhere, didn't work. Tried to force 192.168.1.1 into */etc/resolv.conf*, also didn't work.
- I recently installed PiHole in a container, configured the router to redirect all DNS requests to it and it's working well, from what I can tell. I tried adding a manual DNS record via the PiHole gui, still nothing. Tried adding the server IP manually to */etc/hosts* in the PiHole container... nothing.
- I installed another Ubuntu Server instance in a VM, configuring static IP within the installer and comparing the config files (at least the ones I know about). That's where I got the `search:` line in the netplan yaml file from, unfortunately not much else.

Pinging my Windows 10 PC, which is also configured with a static IP (`ping pc-hostname`) comes back as *192.168.1.2 pc-hostname.fritz.box*.

It's really hard to get info on this. Methods of configuring static IP differ a lot between releases, even between server and desktop of the same release. From the few articles and blog posts I've found with the 20.04 netplan method, none of them appear to do things differently.

**Edit:**

IPs:

```
fritz.box 192.168.1.1
ubuntuserver 192.168.1.4
Win10 192.168.1.2
PiHole 192.168.1.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out, I had to enable MulticastDNS in **/etc/systemd/resolved.conf**:

```
[Resolve]
MulticastDNS=yes
LLMNR=no # You may need to set this as well, not sure
```

Honestly I'm not sure what combination *specifically* did it, I set up a Powershell script in the background, which would beep as soon as it could ping the hostname of the Ubuntu server. I was playing around with the config, with the *resolvectl* utility, changing essentially the same settings as are in this config, just per interface. After I set MulticastDNS the script beeped almost immediately. You will likely need to do a *sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved* before it starts working.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough reputation to comment Sergs answer.

With a Fritzbox 7590 and a ubuntu server with static IP, editing
**/etc/systemd/resolved.conf** works:

```
[Resolve]
MulticastDNS=yes
LLMNR=yes
```

With this config i can ping the machine with its hostname.
In the web frontend of the Fritzbox the hostname of the machine is correct and not PC-192-168-178-XX.

Answer (score 1):

So there's a lot going on here. First, check your DNS configuration.

```
$ nslookup
> server 182.168.1.1
Default server: 192.168.1.1
Address: 192.168.1.1#53
> 192.168.1.4
< Here you will probably get an error >
```

The code example above looks a litte funky, but you are going to want to type nslookup, then "server 192.168.1.1", then the IP of the host you want to query. In this example I picked IPs that you used. The error should come from the DNS entry not being configured.

To configure your DNS, you can probably do two things.

1. Use DHCP, that will likely cause your router to associate your requested name with a DNS entry on your LAN. use "hostnamectl set-hostname yourname" to set your desired hostname.
2. Log into your router and create a static entry for the IP address.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is the result of *nslookup ubuntuserver 192.168.1.1*:
`** server can't find ubuntuserver: NXDOMAIN`
The yaml file is the result of a lot of duckduckgo searches on how to configure a static IP on ubuntu server and then the bridge. Which again, works, apart from the hostname lookup.

Going the router way unfortunately does not produce the desired result. It will give me an IP address within the DHCP range, I can then say to always assign the same IP, but I can't assign my own IP (*.*.*.4), which I'd like to do.

Comment: If you don't want to / can't create a DNS entry, one alternative is to add the machine to your /etc/hosts file on the systems that need to access it.